# Calculate startup time for Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, time

How would you find the time it takes a web api to start up in asp.net mvc? I need a way to time the application from launching to successfully finish loading.

FYI
I could use some javascript to determine the time beforeload and the time afterload and just calculate the difference. But I am not confident if this is the best way to do this.

Comment: Look here to see how to use html5's webperformance http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/

Comment: When you say the application are you referring to the webpage or the web server?

Comment: Web server, more specifically IIS

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to measure the startup time on the server, you could attach a profiler or `DateTime` stamp to `Application_Start` event, then to the `EndRequest` event. `Application_Start` only fires when the application is starting up. Then you could log that data to a text file or database.

Comment: So just before the Application_Start event ends, I would calculate the load time?

Comment: You'd need to start the timer in `Application_Start` when the application is starting up, then calculate the time using `RequestEnd` which is end ASP.NET has served the request to the user.